# В чём суть наполеоновского правила? Что под этим выражением имеет в виду И. С. Тургенев в романе «Отцы и дети»?

Tags: значение-слов, литература

В приведённом отрывке отец Базарова объясняет поведение своего сына наполеоновским правилом:

> Впрочем, Базарову было не до того, чтобы разбирать, что именно
> выражали глаза его матери; он редко обращался к ней, и то с
> коротеньким вопросом. Раз он попросил у ней руку на счастье; она
> тихонько положила свою мягкую ручку на его жесткую и широкую ладонь.
>
> — Что, — спросила она, погодя немного, — не помогло?
>
> — Еще хуже пошло, — отвечал он с небрежною усмешкой.
>
> — Очинно они уже рискуют, — как бы с сожалением произнес отец Алексей
> и погладил свою красивую бороду.
>
> — **Наполеоновское правило**, батюшка, **наполеоновское**, — подхватил Василий
> Иванович и пошел с туза.
>
> — Оно же и довело его до острова Святыя Елены, — промолвил отец
> Алексей и покрыл его туза козырем.

Что под наполеоновским правилом понимает автор?

В Интернете можно найти «мудрости», которые называют наполеоновским правилом:

- «Римское и Наполеоновское правило **divide et impera (разделяй
  и властвуй)**…» [[artofwar.ru](http://artofwar.ru/k/kamenew_anatolij_iwanowich/kutuzowskijstrategion.shtml)]
- «Антиминщики сделали своим руководством к действию известное наполеоновское правило **„Сначала ввяжемся в драку, а потом посмотрим“** ». [[kommersant.ru](https://www.kommersant.ru/doc/13858)]
- «Наполеоновское правило **„бог на стороне больших батальонов“**…» [polit.ru](https://polit.ru/news/2017/07/01/shklovskiy/)
- «Золотое наполеоновское правило — **„армия марширует желудком“**…» [fakty.com.ua](https://fakty.com.ua/ru/svit/20140505-1514044/)
- и т. д.

Исходя из этих примеров можно сделать заключение: всё, что сказал или считается, что сказал Наполеон, всё, что приписывается его мировоззрению можно назвать наполеоновским правилом.

Но что же имел в виду И. С. Тургенев? Ведь если он употребил это выражение, то считал, что читатели должны его понять. Возможно, в те времена под наполеоновским правилом понималось что-то определенное?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень интересный вопрос. Судя по приведённым цитатам, современные журналисты норовят назвать "наполеоновским правилом" одно из многих наполеоновских высказываний, которое сами они приводят явно *не в форме правила*. Из них *правилом* в оригинале было "**Главное - ввязаться в бой...**"; эту фразу использовал в своей риторике даже Ульянов-Ленин - настолько хорошо она была известна. Некоторые цитаты Наполеона (Бог *войны* на стороне больших батальонов; это модификация ранее известной присказки с просто "богом": " Le dieu de *la guerre* est toujours du côté des gros bataillons. "
Napoléon Bonaparte ; Les maximes et pensées /1769-1821/) рассматриваются как правила военной тактики в специальной литературе. Один из трёх основных принципов - создание *превосходства* в нужном месте в нужное время (два других - введение противника в заблуждение и способ построения в несколько линий). Но какой из многочисленных наполеоновских афоризмов ("правило") мог получить такое распространение в быту, что не нуждался в уточнениях?

Пока что мне попался *единственный* старинный пример, где "наполеоновское правило" не называют явно, как и у Тургенева. В трудах по военно-полевой хирургии Пирогова (около 1850 г.) есть фрагмент с комментарием действий его французского коллеги, который проник  в череп пациента на глубину 2,5 см для вскрытия нарыва, что автор оценил как *превышение допустимого риска* даже по меркам "**известного наполеоновского правила**". В современном издании (1961) "правило" снабжено числовой сноской, которую, к сожалению, не посмотреть в результатах поиска. Однако контекст "**риска**" представляется мне близким к туреневскому эпизоду, что наводит на афоризм "**Главное - ввязаться в бой...**" - скорее, чем на "большие батальоны" (крупная карта?), поскольку последняя реплика предположительно указывает на последствия рискованных решений.

Comment: Хороший ответ. Я проголосовал за него и думаю над тем, чтоб принять. У меня такой вопрос: а откуда вам известно, что в издании 1961 года есть сноска? Вы нашли где-то в Интернете текст, в котором стоит сноска? Можете дать ссылку на него.

Comment: «У меня такой вопрос: а откуда вам известно, что в издании 1961 года есть сноска?» Видимо, Alex_ander видел страницу с номером примечания, а сам список примечаний недоступен. Но что касается меня, я бы скорее спросил: «А откуда известно, что автор примечания не ошибается или что это вообще не примечание типа "Неизвестно, о каком наполеоновском правиле здесь идёт речь"?»

Comment: Результат поиска (Начала общей военно-полевой хирургии) - показывается только фрагмент, с цифрой для сноски: https://www.google.ru/books/edition/Nachala_obshche%C4%AD_voenno_polevo%C4%AD_khirur/ge0eAQAAMAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&bsq=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE&dq=%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE

Comment: Я нашёл в сети эту книгу издания 1865 года: https://archive.org/details/nachalaobshcheiv01piro/page/n3/mode/2up Цифры примечания при «нашей» фразе там нет (фрагмент Alex_ander в этом издании — на 140-141 сс.)

Comment: В старом издании и не должно быть пояснений, если первоначально "наполеоновским правилом" называли одно конкретное.

Answer (score 1):

Разумеется, определённое: из вышеприведённых изречений на «правило» (а не афоризм) тянет только одно. Не факт, что его автором является именно Наполеон, но во французском языке такое выражение действительно существует и на самом деле выглядит так: *On s'engage partout et on voit* — «Начнём, а там видно будет». А очень вольный перевод, приплетающий «бой» — или, как в *Коммерсанте*, «драку», — вполне возможно, запустил именно Владимир Ильич.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я не имел в виду, что нужно выбирать из тех вариантов, что я привёл. Это просто примеры и возможно, правильный ответ вообще совершенно другой.

Comment: Если не упомянуты даже ключевые слова «правила», значит, автор полагает, что читатели и без них легко поймут, о чём речь. Следовательно, выбирать действительно надо из самого что ни на есть общеизвестного.